# What is the runtime given a nested loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, big-o, traversal

I am trying to get better at coding, so after each hackerrank challenge, I check to see what other people have done so I can compare my code to theirs. One that came up as an interesting solution, that apparently works, is this:

```js
function getMoneySpent (keyboards, drives, b) {
  return keyboards.reduce (
    (acc, curr) =>
      Math.max (acc, ...drives.map (usb => usb + curr).filter (ku => b >= ku)),
    -1
  );
}

console.log (getMoneySpent ([1, 20, 40], [5, 60, 7], 50));
```

It basically finds the maximum sum of two numbers (one from each array) that are <= a number (50 in this case). However, as I dissected the code it seems like there is two loops, a `.reduce`, and a `.map` with a `.filter`. Does that make this code O(n)^2? I'm pretty sure it would not pass the test cases if it were, as the arrays can be 1000 long, and the number (50) can be 10^6. [Here's](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/electronics-shop/problem) the link to the problem if you're interested.

So after all that my question is - is this code O(n)^2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### As far as I can see, it's actually `3•O(n)^2`

See below for reasoning:

```js
function getMoneySpent (keyboards, drives, b) {
                // O(n)
  return keyboards.reduce ( 
    (acc, curr) =>
        // O(n) +              O(n) +                  O(n)
      Math.max (acc, ...drives.map (usb => usb + curr).filter (ku => b >= ku)),
    -1
  );
}
```

```
O(n) * (O(n) + O(n) + O(n))
O(n) * 3•O(n)
3•O(n)^2
```

[Math.max source code](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/cd81dd6d740ff82a1abbc68615e8769bd467f91e/src/js/math.js#L77-L102)